# Can we Automate Mainframe using PowerTerm and VBA/Excel Macro?

Tags: excel, vba

We have automated Mainframe Application POC using Rocket Bluezone..

The PowerTerm manuals also says "High-level API enables access from other environments, such as C++, Visual Basic, and Power Builder. Also supports HLLAPI, EHLLAPI, and WinHLLAPI"

Anybody has sample code to automate PowerTerm using VBA..

PowerTerm has inbuilt record tool.. Also It has `Tools -> Macros -> Visual Basic Editor ..`

Sample code..

```
Sub Login()
    Send ("L TEL1")
    Send "<ENTER>"
End Sub
```

It interacts with PowerTerm when you run from Menu option. but I need to know how to call externally using VBS..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following VBS-Code to run a Macro from an Excel-Workbook:

```vb
Dim ObjExcel, ObjWB
Set ObjExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set ObjWB = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("Path_To_Excel_Workbook")
ObjWB.Application.Run "Macro_Name"
ObjWB.Close False
ObjExcel.Quit
Set ObjWB = Nothing
Set ObjExcel = Nothing
```

Just open a new text file, copy and save as `.vbs`

Comment: From PowerTerm if we save that vba it is getting saved as .pcf.. not in the xlsm format

Comment: @ChanGan I think i misunderstood your question... I thought you wanted to call a vbs script from somewhere else. What is it you want to accomplish exactly?